# How to protect layout from malformatted html content on a generated webpage?

Tags: dynamic, html, malformed

I have a container layout of a webpage that works like this:

```
<html>
#header#
<div class="content_container"> #content inserted here# </div>
#footer#
</html>
```

If the content has a `div` that is not closed or closes a `div` without it being opened, the `content_container`'s div and so the layout gets messed up.

How is this situation normally avoided or solved?

Comment: having all tags properly opened and closed?

Comment: How is content retrieved/inserted? Are you using AJAX for that? Straight from PHP or some other preprocessor?

Comment: it's "dynamic" via a (effectively) preprocessor, not PHP but web2py this time. no AJAX (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,

From what i found on the net, you could parse the fragment as a HTML document using the DOM loadHTML function, then spit it back out again as HTML. That will fix any HTML well-formedness errors.

Or you could use the Tidy extension for php5

http://www.php.net/tidy